Tabular table too wide for page
My table is to wide and won't fit in the page. Any help making make it sure it fits?
Here is what I am working with:
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\caption{Interaction term coefficients and statistical significance }
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
Coef. of the interaction term & Policy introspection A & Policy external view B & Policy non-responsive C & Policy coverage incomplete D \\
\hline
Variable 1*Attitudes toward civics & $-^{*}$ & $+^{*}$ & $p>0.05$ & $p>0.05$. \\
\hline
Variable 2*Attitudes toward maths & $p>0.05$ & $p>0.05$ & $+^{*}$ & $-^{*}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}


see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809482/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-an-entire-latex-table
